# How can I select a non-sequential subset elements from an array using Scala and Spark?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

In Python, this is how I would do it.

```
>>> x
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2])
>>> x[np.array([3, 3, 1, 8])]
array([7, 7, 9, 2])
```

This doesn't work in the Scala Spark shell:

```
scala> val indices = Array(3,2,0)
indices: Array[Int] = Array(3, 2, 0)

scala> val A = Array(10,11,12,13,14,15)
A: Array[Int] = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

scala> A(indices)
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Int]
 required: Int
              A(indices)
```

The foreach method doesn't work either:

```
scala> indices.foreach(println(_))
3
2
0

scala> indices.foreach(A(_))
<no output>
```

What I want is the result of B:

```
scala> val B = Array(A(3),A(2),A(0))
B: Array[Int] = Array(13, 12, 10)
```

However, I don't want to hard code it like that because I don't know how long indices is or what would be in it.

Comment: like this? `val x = Array(10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2); Array(3, 3, 1, 8).map(x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most concise way I can think of is to flip your mental model and put indices first:

```
indices map A
```

And, I would potentially suggest using `lift` to return an `Option`

```
indices map A.lift
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map` on `indices`, which maps each element to a new element based on a mapping lambda.  Note that on `Array`, you get an element at an index with the `apply` method:

```
indices.map(index => A.apply(index))
```

You can leave off `apply`:

```
indices.map(index => A(index))
```

You can also use the underscore syntax:

```
indices.map(A(_))
```

When you're in a situation like this, you can even leave off the underscore:

```
indices.map(A)
```

And you can use the alternate space syntax:

```
indices map A
```

You were trying to use `foreach`, which returns `Unit`, and is only used for side effects. For example:

```
indices.foreach(index => println(A(index)))
indices.map(A).foreach(println)
indices map A foreach println
```